# Pulseaudio: Two headphones (bluetooth, analog-stereo)

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I'm trying to listen to a video from two headphones, one connected via bluetooth and one connected by cable.

Both options work on their own, but I cannot get the combination to work.

I'm using the following command:

```
$ pacmd load-module module-combine-sink \
  sink_name=combined5 \
  slaves=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo,bluez_sink.70_26_05_89_B1_2F.a2dp_sink \
  sink_properties=device.description=myCombine5 \
  pacmd set-default-sink combined5
```

To validate the setup, I used both `mplayer` and `vlc` and checked that the new sink was indeed used with `pavucontrol`.

To my surprise the output of the new sink arrives only at the headphones connected by cable. The bluetooth headphones are dead silent. I restarted `pulseaudio` with `-v` and looked at its log output, but could not find any error.

Any ideas, what else I could do or check?

EDIT: I added the output of pacmd list-sinks:

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
6 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo-extra2>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9030
    volume: front-left: 64525 /  98% / -0.41 dB,   front-right: 64525 /  98% / -0.41 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 1999.82 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 2"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 2"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "8"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf0630000 irq 50"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0a0c"
        device.product.name = "Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "hdmi:0,2"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352768"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176384"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo-extra2"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI 3)"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI 3)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel Haswell HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:80862807,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    active port: <hdmi-output-2>
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 65217 / 100% / -0.13 dB,   front-right: 65217 / 100% / -0.13 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: yes
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC3232 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC3232 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf0634000 irq 48"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card2"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9c20"
        device.product.name = "8 Series HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:2"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC3232"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0292,17aa220c,00100001"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
    index: 2
    name: <bluez_sink.70_26_05_89_B1_2F.a2dp_sink>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9050
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 3 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 2
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 45.32 ms
    card: 2 <bluez_card.70_26_05_89_B1_2F>
    module: 26
    properties:
        bluetooth.protocol = "a2dp_sink"
        device.description = "WH-1000XM2"
        device.string = "70:26:05:89:B1:2F"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_70_26_05_89_B1_2F"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "WH-1000XM2"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    ports:
        headset-output: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

    active port: <headset-output>
* index: 3
    name: <combined5>
    driver: <module-combine-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 7 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 3
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 200.00 ms
    module: 27
    properties:
        device.class = "filter"
        combine.slaves = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo,bluez_sink.70_26_05_89_B1_2F.a2dp_sink"
        device.description = "myCombine5"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    index: 4
    name: <combined5.2>
    driver: <module-combine-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 7 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 4
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 200.00 ms
    module: 28
    properties:
        device.class = "filter"
        combine.slaves = "bluez_sink.70_26_05_89_B1_2F.a2dp_sink"
        device.description = "myCombineX"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    index: 5
    name: <combinedX>
    driver: <module-combine-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 7 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 5
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 200.00 ms
    module: 29
    properties:
        device.class = "filter"
        combine.slaves = "bluez_sink.70_26_05_89_B1_2F.a2dp_sink"
        device.description = "myCombineX"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

EDIT: As described in the comments I added a combined sink containing only the bluetooth headphones. I played a track with paplay and then compared the output of pacmd list-sinks for this source with the same for the regular bluetooth sink. In the following I show the output of only the line that changed:

Using bluetooth

```
  * index: 2
    name: <bluez_sink.70_26_05_89_B1_2F.a2dp_sink>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    current latency: 63.37 ms

    index: 3
    name: <combinedX>
    driver: <module-combine-sink.c>
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    max request: 7 KiB
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 200.00 ms
```

Using combined sink

```
  * index: 2
    name: <bluez_sink.70_26_05_89_B1_2F.a2dp_sink>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    current latency: 63.88 ms

    index: 3
    name: <combinedX>
    driver: <module-combine-sink.c>
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    max request: 3 KiB
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 45.32 ms; range is 45.32 .. 45.32 ms
```

Comment: What happens if you choose the bluez sink as an output for a second stream (`paplay` with sink on commandline, or `mplayer` etc. toether with `pavucontrol`) while output to the combined sink is active? I don't have a bluetooth headphone, but does `pacmd list` etc. show the sink status of a bluetooth sink?

Comment: When I try `pacmd load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combinedX slaves=bluez_sink.70_26_05_89_B1_2F.a2dp_sink sink_properties=device.description=myCombineX` followed by `paplay -d combinedX music.flac` I get no response in the bluetooth headphones, same with the above `combined5`.  Again I hear sounds in my bluetooth headphones works with `paplay -d bluez_sink.70_26_05_89_B1_2F.a2dp_sink music.flac`

Comment: Hm. Can you play something to the combined sink, and while it's playing, check `state`, `used by`, and `linked by` of the BT sink with `pacmd list-sinks`? Is it still suspended, even when the combined sink is not?

Comment: Hi dirkt, sorry for the long delay. I changed the question to include the ouput you requested. In short the bluetooth sink is in the state `RUNNING` in both cases.

Comment: It's RUNNING but no sound? That's really odd. Volume(s) are ok, nothing muted? If yes I guess one would have to debug the bluez sink module to figure out what goes wrong...

Comment: I turned the volume of the bluetooth headphones way up in the commandline `pactl set-sink-volume 9 300%` and hey it works! So I assume (under the assumption that nothing strange happened in the mean time) that the volume was previously simply too low. The behavior is still strange as I really have to crank up the volume in the combined case, while in the bluetooth-only case I can work with 100% just fine. In any case that solves my problem :D